# Как передать файл с USB-устройства на компьютер (Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Необходимо чтобы по нажатию кнопки файл с телефона, подключенного к компьютеру через Usb, копировался на жёсткий диск. Как можно это реализовать в Delphi?

Comment: Сделать это очень легко, но смотря какой телефон и смотря что установлено на компьютере...

Comment: @DiD Телефон восьмой андроид Huawei, мне нужно передать с этого телефона музыкальный файл на компьютер

Comment: есть два варианта: по протоколу MTP (требует установленный драйвер) или через запущенный сервер adb (для запуска adb требуются права администратора)